# How to echo few lines only from a row named body saved in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I want to echo only summary of my blog post on a certain page by making a function() that must limit the number of counts of words as specified there.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumarize($your_string){
   $count++;
   $maximum = 10;
   foreach(explode("\n", $your_string) as $line){
       $count++;
       echo $line."\n";
       if ($count == $maximum) break;        
   }
}
```

Comment: But how to use this? Basically I have a functions.php file in which I save all the function and then use it on the page where i want to echo the text.

Comment: wont take care of spaces by html 'nbsp'

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh: sorry, I didn't get this

Comment: @genesis φ I can not understand "$your_string", what must be passed here, as I have my string saved in mysql's row.

Answer (score 0):

this one takes into account numbers of character whilst ending at the last word without cutting out a character

use

```
select .... SUBSTR(body,1,300) .....
```

later you can use this function in php to cut the string at the last space or period so you wont get a half cut word in the end. The second parameter is the number of characters you want.

```
function shorten_string($string, $characters)
{
    $shortened_string = "";
    $smaller_string = substr($string, 0, $characters);
    $pos_of_last_space = strrpos($smaller_string, " ");
    $pos_of_last_break = strrpos($smaller_string, "&nbsp;");

    if (strlen($string) <= $characters) {
        $shortened_string = $string;
    } elseif (!$pos_of_last_space && !$pos_of_last_break) {
        $shortened_string = $smaller_string;
    } else {
        $break_at = 0;
        if ($pos_of_last_space > $pos_of_last_break) {
            $break_at = $pos_of_last_space;
        } else {
            $break_at = $pos_of_last_break;
        }

        $shortened_string = substr($smaller_string, 0, $break_at);
    }
}
```

**NOTE: takes care of spaces put in html with 'nbsp'**

Comment: what is that? the bunch of code for nothing. Take a look at genesis φ's solution

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu - what if you have html nbsp for character spaces?

Comment: But how to use this? Basically I have a functions.php file in which I save all the function and then use it on the page where i want to echo the text. And where i must put the query?

Comment: @James - put the function in the file where you put all your functions. Forget about the sql query for now. Call this function passing your string along with the max number of characters you want

Comment: can you please give me the syntax how to pass the string with the desired number of characters by taking an example?

Comment: $summarizedText = shorten_string($body,200);

Comment: the function shorten_string which i pasted above should be placed in your functions file

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your table (named **main**) looks like that.

### id | blogpost

1    sample1

2    sample2
...

At first you need to connect to db

```
$db=NEW MYSQLI('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'dbname') or die ($db->error);
```

Then write following piece of code

```
function sumarize($your_string){
   $count++;
   $maximum = 10;
   foreach(explode("\n", $your_string) as $line){
       $count++;
       echo $line."\n";
       if ($count == $maximum) break;        
   }
}

$result=$db->query("SELECT `id`, `blogpost` FROM `main`");
while($row->fetch_object()){
echo sumarize($row->blogpost);
}
```

This is how to get work genesis φ's solution

Answer (score -1):

Save the summary and body of your blog posts in different columns.

Comment: It will load server with extra queries

Comment: i think you need to get some sleep

Comment: @Tural, how would it load the server more?  For pages where you want both body and summary, you `SELECT body, summary`, for those where you only need the summary, you `SELECT summary`.  No extra queries required.

Comment: Also note that it didn't mention having a specific word limit for summaries in the original question.

Comment: If there will be, lets say 10 000 posts, your solution - selecting 2 columns, will affect the performance (it selects unneeded columns, and your data packets get larger), but @genesis φ's solution - selecting 1 column and making summary with php function, will do the same thing without allocating more memory for 1 more unneeded column

Comment: At first times, selecting 1 columns versus 2 columns might not have a noticeable impact performance wise but as tables get larger and wider you will notice a performance difference. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, it really depends on the specifics of how this is used - eg if the summary page gets a lot of hits (which seems quite likely to me, eg if it was the homepage) then my approach will benefit, since you don't have to do all that processing in PHP.  Also my approach is more flexible, since you're not hard-coding the summary size, but can tailor a summary for each post.